# Get mouse position on screen (no application window) WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I create app with will work in background. On Button click i want to show window in the place where the mouse is. I have to take it relative to the whole screen and not some window.

In all posts there will be someone who inserts to use:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
```

But I cant use it in wpf.

For me it could even be taken from the command line or power shell.

Comment: In order to use `System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition` you would need to add assembly references to `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Forms`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 solutions I know of, one, the arguably worse one is to calculate it based on the widow position and cursor-window position.

The other one, uses [PInvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/).

```cs
static class Cursor {
    internal struct POINT {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos ( out POINT lpPoint );

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos ( int X, int Y );

    public static POINT Position {
        get {
            GetCursorPos( out POINT point );
            return point;
        }
        set {
            SetCursorPos( value.X, value.Y );
        }
    }
}
```